# What is the blood status of a person born to a half-blood and pure-blood?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

I see that people born to parents who are both magical are pure-bloods, if either of the parental sides is muggle they are half-bloods, and if both the parents are muggles, the child is muggle-born.

But what is the blood status of the child born to a half-blood and a pure-blood? Since there are muggles in the ancestral line is he/she still a half-blood, or considering that both the parents are magical, is he/she a pure-blood?

Comment: Anyone with a lower fraction of wizard blood as yours is a filthy half-blood at best; anyone with the same or higher fraction is practically a pure wizard.

Comment: There's also the practical problem of proving someone was "pure-blood" in the first place. Even if you can trace your lineage accurately back to the first wizards (a tall order, both because it's hard to keep records that far back and because people have reason to lie), you still can't be sure whether the original was "pure-blood." Which I've always assumed was part of the point, as it's also true with racism in the real world, too.

Comment: Three-quarters blood?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Children of Pure-bloods and Half-bloods are Half-bloods

JKR has stated on her old website that this was the case, however was quick to establish that this would only be of importance to those who feel the need to prejudice to that extent

> The expressions 'pure-blood', 'half-blood' and 'Muggle-born' have been coined by people to whom these distinctions matter, and express their originators' prejudices. **As far as somebody like Lucius Malfoy is concerned, for instance, a Muggle-born is as 'bad' as a Muggle.** **Therefore Harry would be considered only 'half' wizard**, because of his mother's grandparents.
>   <sub>[FAQ at J. K. Rowling's Official Site](https://web.archive.org/web/20060316221500/https://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=58)</sub>

This is re-iterated by Bellatrix Lestrange in the fifth book.

> “Shut your mouth!” Bellatrix shrieked. “You dare speak his name
>   with your unworthy lips, you dare besmirch it with your half-blood’s
>   tongue, you dare —”
>
> ...
>
> “He dared — he dares —” shrieked Bellatrix incoherently. “— He
>   stands there — filthy half-blood —”
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 35 (Beyond the Veil)</sub>

There was, however, precedence for pure-blood families to allow half-bloods to marry into their bloodlines:

> From the imposition of the Statute of Secrecy onwards, no Malfoy has married a Muggle or Muggle-born. The family has, however, eschewed the somewhat dangerous practice of inter-marrying within such a small pool of pure-bloods that they become enfeebled or unstable, **unlike a small minority of fanatic families such as the Gaunts and Lestranges, and many a half-blood appears on the Malfoy family tree.**
>   <sub>[The Malfoy family - Writing by J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-malfoy-family)</sub>

Although there remained those families that married only within pure-blood circles, such as the Gaunts and the Lestranges, listed above.

> Centuries it’s been in our family, that’s how far back we go, **and pure-blood all the way!**
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 10 (The House of Gaunt)</sub>

It is worth noting that although most Death Eaters were half-blood, they would've pretended to be pure-blooded and resented their muggle sides. (Such as Voldemort and Snape did)

> "“The Death Eaters can’t all be pure-blood, there aren’t enough pure-blood wizards left,” said Hermione stubbornly. “I expect most of them are half-bloods pretending to be pure. It’s only Muggle-borns they hate, they’d be quite happy to let you and Ron join up.”
>   <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 12 (Silver and Opals)</sub>

Comment: > 'Dirty blood.' Why, there isn't a wizard alive today that's not half-blood or less."

Answer (score 0):

If you are born to a half-blood and a pure-blood you are a pure-blood. Because, you have three parts pure-blood and one part half-blood the pure-blood over rules it. Therefore, Albus, James,and Lilly Potter are pure-bloods. That is how Albus is in Slytherin, which only takes pure-bloods.

Comment: Sorry, but if Slytherin only took pure-bloods then Severus Snape would never have ended up there. Snape's father is a muggle (not a muggleborn, just plain muggle).